# What's the best way to deal with a normalized response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, normalizr

I'm using normalizr to normalize a response.

My problem is that I don't know how to manage the normalized response.

```
{
  result:[]
  entities: {
    words: {
      //...
      1: {
       definitions: [1, 2, 3]
      }
      // other word objects...      
    },
    definitions: {

      1: 'blah blah'
      2: 'blah blah'
      3: 'blah blah'
      // definition objects
    }
  }
}
```

I want to pass the words to a react component with definitions. How can I retrieve the words with nested definitions and render it to my component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[webpackbin DEMO](http://www.webpackbin.com/EypsNtYvW)**

assuming that your state looks something like this

```
entities: {
    words: {
        //...
        1: {
            id:1,
            text:"Word",
            definitions: [1, 2, 3]
        },
        // other word objects...
    },
    definitions: {
        1: {id:1, text:'blah blah'},
        2: {id:2, text:'blah blah'},
        3: {id:3, text:'blah blah'},
        // definition objects
    }
},
wordsById : [1,4,7,8,22]
```

then... WordList may looks like this. Slice ids of words from state, in order to render list

```
const WordList = ({ids}) => <div>{ids.map(id => <Word id={id} key={id}/>)}</div>;

export default connect(state =>({ ids:state.wordsById }))(WordList);
```

and Word component: Get particular word from state by id from props, calculate definitions list through map

```
const Word = ({word, definitions}) =>(
    <div className="word-block">
        <span>{word.text}</span>
        <DefinitionsList definitions={definitions}/>
    </div>
)

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) =>{
    const word = state.entities.words[props.id];
    const { definitions:ids } = word
    return {
        word,
        definitions:ids.map(id => state.entities.definitions[id])
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Word);
```

and DefinitionsList

```
const DefinitionsList = ({definitions})=> (
    <div className="definitions">
        {definitions.map(def =><div key={def.id}>{def.text}</div>)}
    </div>
);
```

Functional compontent was used just for short.