# How to avoid re-renders in nested lists in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have hierarchical, recursive data structure. It's a list of named items and every item can have its own sub-list of items. It looks like this:

```
const items = [
    {
        name: 'item1',
        items: [
            {name: 'item2'},
            {name: 'item3'},
            {name: 'item4', items: [
                {
                    name: 'item5'
                }
            ]},
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'item6'
    }
]
```

I want to display it in unordered list with nested sub-lists. Also I need the ability to mark some items as highlighted and to dehighlight all items. Because of the second requirement information about highlighted items must live in top level component.

My naive implementation looks like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments)
        this.state = {
            items: items,
            highlightedItemsNames: {},
        }
        this.handleHighligtItem = (item) => {
            this.setState({highlightedItemsNames: {
                ...this.state.highlightedItemsNames, [item.name]: true
            }})
        }
        this.handleDehighlightAllItems = () => {
            this.setState({highlightedItemsNames: {}})
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleDehighlightAllItems}>dehighlight</button>
            <List
                items={this.state.items}
                highlightedItemsNames={this.state.highlightedItemsNames}
                onHighlight={this.handleHighligtItem}
            />
        </div>
    }
}


function List(props) {
    return <ul>
        {props.items.map(item => <li key={item.name}>
            <Item
                item={item}
                highlighted={props.highlightedItemsNames[item.name]}
                highlightedItemsNames={props.highlightedItemsNames}
                onHighlight={props.onHighlight}
            />
        </li>)}
    </ul>
}


function Item(props) {
    let className = "item"
    if (props.highlighted) {
        className += '-highlighted'
    }
    console.log('renders item', props.item.name)
    return <div>
        <span className={className}>{props.item.name}</span>
        <button onClick={() => props.onHighlight(props.item)}>highlight</button>
        {props.item.items ? <List
            items={props.item.items}
            highlightedItemsNames={props.highlightedItemsNames}
            onHighlight={props.onHighlight}
        /> : null}
    </div>
}
```

But now when I highlight an item `highlightedItemsNames` changes and every `Item` re-renders. To display data correctly only the highlighted item and its parents need to re-render. So how can I avoid all of those unnecessary re-renders?

In my application list of items can be a bit big and re-rendering all of it causes app to noticeably freeze on click.

I could implement `shouldComponentUpdate` in `Item` that checks if any sub-item should be re-rendered but does this have an actual chance to improve performance over virtual-dom?

I'm not using Redux or any other state management library and I'd rather not do this at this point.

Comment: You need to set unique keys to the elements. Otherwise it will always re-render.

Comment: check this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent

Comment: @MuratK. Item names are unique - so I have unique prop on <li>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid re-rendering a big list of items with react-redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702342/avoid-re-rendering-a-big-list-of-items-with-react-redux)

Comment: @FabioAntunes I'm not using Redux

Comment: @MayankShukla Could you tell me how using PureComponent instead of functional one will help me?

Answer (score 1):

`ShouldComponentUpdate` is meant for the purpose of check and decide whether re-render is needed or not. It is obviously a wise decision to implement in cases where large items are re-rendering unnecessarily. I guess you should try to implement this event and see the performance. I believe trying is what makes most things perfect.